# Popup alert user before delete TableViewCell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

title basically says it; surprised I couldn't find anything on stack overview but none helped me or were in objective C

I have a table view with a list of items and an edit button that allows user to delete rows (can also 'swipe to delete'). basically, I want to have a popup alert that says "are you sure you want to delete (rowname)" where row name is the name of the row about to be deleted. from what I have found/tried, I can get the popup BUT it shows up every time you press the edit button or swipe right. I only want the popup to appear when the user presses "delete".

and, obviously, from the popup if they press Cancel it should cancel, if they press delete it should delete

how do you do this in general?

sorry I am kind of a noob

Comment: What's wrong with the Objective-C answers? It's the same APIs. Just translate the code to Swift.

Comment: Show your current code and your current attempt to do what you wish to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is present the alert when the button is pressed and set each action.

Replace your `commit editingStyle` delegate method with this and replace the `data` variable with your data array:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        presentDeletionFailsafe(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}

func presentDeletionFailsafe(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Are you sure you'd like to delete this cell", preferredStyle: .alert)

    // yes action
    let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) { _ in
        // replace data variable with your own data array
        self.data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }

    alert.addAction(yesAction)

    // cancel action
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**EDIT**

Example:

```
private let reuseId = "cellReuseId"

class SlideToDeleteViewController : UIViewController {
    lazy var tableView = createTableView()

    func createTableView() -> UITableView {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        return tableView
    }

    var data = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

    override func loadView() {
        self.view = tableView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension SlideToDeleteViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseId)
        cell?.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            presentDeletionFailsafe(indexPath: indexPath)
        }
    }

    func presentDeletionFailsafe(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Are you sure you'd like to delete this cell", preferredStyle: .alert)

        // yes action
        let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) { _ in
            // put code to remove tableView cell here
            self.data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }

        alert.addAction(yesAction)

        // cancel action
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: so I dont' have a delete button - it's just the default delete button that comes up when you press "edit", do you know what I mean? how do you create an outlet for that? or how do you reference it?

Comment: Oh, gotcha. @LegalFingers Please see my edited answer and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @LegalFingers If my edited answer is correct would you mind accepting it as the correct answer? I just threw together an example in playground showing how to do it and added it to my post.